# Which editor does GitLab use for issues?

Tags: editor, markdown, gitlab

I am looking for the source of the embedded markdown editor that GitLab uses in their issue tracker. It looks like this:

[image: Picture of the GitLab editor]

Note that this is *not* the same as the code editor they use e.g. to display the source of files within the repository. I am hoping that the above editor is (some extension of) an open-source project, but I could not find it.

Comment: Actually it would appear not to be a standalone project: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/preview_markdown.js